# Open a fixed Image from memory using Camera Plugin

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, android-camera

Im using Camera-Plugin from phonegap. I learned that we can either use Camera or the File system to get an Image.

Now I want to get the ImageURL of an image (with path already known) to display it using

`var image = document.getElementById('myImage');
image.src = imageURL;`

in the `successCallBack`.
 The image path is  `/storage/emulated/0/Images/1.png`.

Looking for help and guidance . Anything is appreciated

Comment: When selecting a file using the file picker, you also need to set the CameraOptions object. In cameraSuccess function you get imageUri so you can use that imageUri as source of image that you want to show.

Comment: I'm not letting the user to pick the image using image picker  
How can I pass the Imageuri without selecting it ?

Comment: So basically you need to know the url of that image. Store image with your file name (you can do it using file plugin), now you know the url of your image so you can directly assing in src. Let me know if it is not clear.

Comment: I have displayed the image already. Now I want to replace the image with a newer one with the same file name.